# Reading tiff image stack in Java

Tags: java, image, stack, tiff

I have a video file that is a sequence of `.tif` images.  The video itself is the R of an RGB video so the pixel values are `int`.  I need to open each image as an int pixel array.  I can open tiff files but this is a whole stack of images.

Specifically my question is:  Does anyone know how to represent a `.tif` image sequence(stack) as a 3D array indexed by `frame, x_pos, y_pos` in Java?  Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: for java i recommend BIO-FORMATS just give it a try